# How can I refactor this code efficiently?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I've created some C# code that uses the EWS API. Mostly google-fu as I have only been writing things in C# for a couple of weeks. My boss has tasked me with refactoring the code to match a certain style, but I'm completely lost (as I don't know what I'm doing!)

I've tried multiple changes to the code, but always faced with a sea of red.
I've used the built in refactoring, but it's creating new methods and still isn't compiling.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
        ConfigureExchangeSearchResults(out ExchangeService service, out SearchFilter sf, out ItemView view);

        if (Settings.Default.envLive == true)
        {
            findResults = ProcessLiveEmails(service, sf, view);
        }
        else
        {
            FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(int.MaxValue));
            foreach (Folder folder in findFolderResults.Folders)
            {
                logger.Info(folder.DisplayName);
                if (folder.DisplayName == Settings.Default.envFolder)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        findResults = service.FindItems(folder.Id, sf, view);
                        logger.Info("Found " + findResults.TotalCount + " Messages");
                        foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
                        {
                            logger.Info(item.DateTimeReceived);
                            EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments, ItemSchema.HasAttachments, EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived));
                            CheckMessageReceivedDate(message);
                            message.IsRead = true;
                                message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
                        }
                    }
                    while (findResults.MoreAvailable);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.Error(e, "Error Occured On: " + DateTime.Now + " - Error Details: " + e.Message);
    }
    NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

That's my current code. I've been asked to refactor it to this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        ExchangeService service;
        SearchFilter sf;
        ItemView view;
        ConfigureExchangeSearchParameters(out service, out sf, out view);

        if (settings.Default.envLive == true)
        {
            ProcessLiveEmails(service, sf, view);
        }
        else
        {
            ProcessTestEmails(service, sf, view);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.Error(e, "Error Occurred On: " + DateTime.Now + " - Error Details: " + e.Message);
    }
    NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

I've got a couple of C# training courses lined up later this month, but I need to get this sorted before I go!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ETA:
Here are the refactored methods for ProcessLiveEmails and ProcessTestEmails:

```
 private static FindItemsResults<Item> ProcessTestEmails(ExchangeService service, SearchFilter sf, ItemView view)
    {
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
        FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(int.MaxValue));
        foreach (Folder folder in findFolderResults.Folders)
        {
            logger.Info(folder.DisplayName);
            if (folder.DisplayName == Settings.Default.envFolder)
            {
                do
                {
                    findResults = service.FindItems(folder.Id, sf, view);
                    logger.Info("Found " + findResults.TotalCount + " Messages");
                    foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
                    {
                        logger.Info(item.DateTimeReceived);
                        EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments, ItemSchema.HasAttachments, EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived));
                        CheckMessageReceivedDate(message);
                        message.IsRead = true;
                        message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
                    }
                }
                while (findResults.MoreAvailable);
            }
        }

       return findResults;
    }

    private static void ConfigureExchangeSearchResults(out ExchangeService service, out SearchFilter sf, out ItemView view)
    {
        service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2)
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true
        };
        service.AutodiscoverUrl(Properties.Settings.Default.autoURL, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
        sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
        view = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
        view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending);
    }





    private static FindItemsResults<Item> ProcessLiveEmails(ExchangeService service, SearchFilter sf, ItemView view)
    {
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
        do
        {
            findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, view);
            logger.Info("Found " + findResults.TotalCount + " Messages");
            foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
            {
                logger.Info(item.DateTimeReceived);
                EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments, ItemSchema.HasAttachments, EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived));
                CheckMessageReceivedDate(message);
                message.IsRead = true;
                message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
            }
        }
        while (findResults.MoreAvailable);
        return findResults;
    }
```

ProcessLiveEmails seems to be fine, the issue is with ProcessTestEmails, specifically the last line:

```
return findResults;
```

Comment: The second section of code is how I'm supposed to refactor it to

Comment: And what is your question then? Seems like you should simply extract a method from your current else-branch.

Comment: You aren't using `findResults` in the `envLive == true` case so if you move the declaration into the `else` branch you should be able to extract that block into a `ProcessTestEmails` method.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - I have tried refactoring, but I get the error:
Use of unassigned local variable findResults in the refactored method.

Comment: If you have an error, please include the message in your question. In this case it looks like `findResults` is not definitely assigned when you return it so you should initialise it in the declaration i.e. `FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = new indItemsResults<Item>()` (assuming it has a default constructor).